# Getting error constants.js:116 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid currency code : â¦ with Intl

Tags: javascript

Getting  Uncaught RangeError: Invalid currency code : â¦

even though the currency code is correct
see my function below

```
export const toCommaAmount = (origNum) => {
    console.log("inside toCommaAmount")
    let newNum = origNum
    if (origNum !== null) {
        if (typeof origNum == 'string') {
            newNum = Number(origNum);
        }
        const options = {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: '\u20A6'
        }

        const intNum = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', options).format(newNum);
        return intNum.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Provide some more details, What is your input, what is your expected output ?

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#options) you can see that the value of `currency` can only be [ISO 4217](https://www.six-group.com/dam/download/financial-information/data-center/iso-currrency/lists/list-one.xml) currency codes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
thanks

```
export const toCommaAmount = (origNum) => {
    console.log("inside toCommaAmount")
    let newNum = origNum
    if (origNum !== null) {
        if (typeof origNum == 'string') {
            newNum = Number(origNum);
        }
        const options = {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'NGN',
            currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            maximumFractionDigits: 0,
            currencySign: 'accounting'
        }

        const intNum = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NG', options).format(newNum);
        const formatted = intNum.replace(/(?<=\d)NGN/g, '\u20A6');
        return formatted.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#options) you can see that the value of `currency` can only be [ISO 4217](https://www.six-group.com/dam/download/financial-information/data-center/iso-currrency/lists/list-one.xml) currency codes.

So for Nigeria (as far is I'm aware `\u20A6` is the currency symbol for Naira) you can use:

```js
const toCommaAmount = (origNum) => {
  console.log("inside toCommaAmount")
  let newNum = origNum
  if (origNum !== null) {
    if (typeof origNum == 'string') {
      newNum = Number(origNum);
    }
    const options = {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'NGN'
    }

    const intNum = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', options).format(newNum);
    return intNum.toString()
  }
}

console.log(toCommaAmount(12345));
```